# Anonymisation of xMillion entries - need performance hints

Tags: python, performance, gpu

**Edit:** it was huge mistake to initialize name-dataset on each call (its loading the blacklist-name-dataset into memory).
Just moved *m = NameDataset()* to the main function. Did not measured, but its now at least 100 times faster.

---

I developed a (multilingual) and fast searchable DB with [dataTables](https://datatables.net/). I want to anonymize some data (names etc.) from the MySQL DB.
In first instance I used spaCy - but hence the dictionaries were not trained - the result had too much false-positives. Right now I am pretty happy with [name-dataset](https://github.com/philipperemy/name-dataset). Its working completely different of course and its much slower as spaCy, which benefits of GPU-Power.

Hence the custom names-DB got pretty big (350.000 lines) and target DB is huge - the processing of each found word with *regex.finditer* in a loop takes for ever (Ryzen 7 3700X).
We can say 5 cases/sec - which makes >100 hours for some Million rows.
Hence each process eats just about 10% CPU power, I start several (up to 10) python processes - on the end its still takes too long.

I hope, I never have to do this again - but I am afraid, that I have to.
Thatswhy I ask, do you have any performance tipps for the following routines?

- the outer for loop in main() - which is looping through the piped object (the DB rows) and calls three times (= 3 items/columns) anonymize()
- which has a for loop as well, which runs through each found word

Would it make sense to rewrite them, to use CUDA/numba (RTX 2070 available) etc.?
Any other performance tipps? Thanks!

```
import simplejson as json
import sys, regex, logging, os
from names_dataset import NameDataset

def anonymize(sourceString, col):
    replacement = 'xxx'
    output = ''
    words = sourceString.split(' ')
    #and this second loop for each word (will run three times per row)
    for word in words:
        newword = word
        #regex for findind/splitting the words
        fRegExStr = r'(?=[^\s\r\n|\(|\)])(\w+)(?=[\.\?:,!\-/\s\(\)]|$)'
        pattern = regex.compile(fRegExStr)
        regx = pattern.finditer(word)
        if regx is None:
            if m.search_first_name(word, use_upper_Row=True):
                output += replacement
            elif m.search_last_name(word, use_upper_Row=True):
                output += replacement
            else:
                output += word
        else:
            for eachword in regx:
                if m.search_first_name(eachword.group(), use_upper_Row=True):
                    newword = newword.replace(eachword.group(), replacement)
                elif m.search_last_name(eachword.group(), use_upper_Row=True):
                    newword = newword.replace(eachword.group(), replacement)
            output += newword
        output += ' '
    return output

def main():
    #object with data is been piped to the python script, data structure:
    #MyRows: {
    #   [Text_A: 'some text', Text_B: 'some more text', Text_C: 'still text'],
    #   [Text_A: 'some text', Text_B: 'some more text', Text_C: 'still text'],
    #   ....several thousand rows
    #   }
    MyRows = json.load(sys.stdin, 'utf-8')
    #this is the first outer loop for each row
    for Row in MyRows:
        xText_A = Row['Text_A']
        if Row['Text_A'] and len(Row['Text_A']) > 30:
            Row['Text_A'] = anonymize(xText_A, 'Text_A')
        xText_B = Row['Text_B']
        if xText_B and len(xText_B) > 10:
            Row['Text_B'] = anonymize(xText_B, 'Text_B')
        xMyRowText_C = Row['MyRowText_C']
        if xMyRowText_C and len(xMyRowText_C) > 10:
            Row['MyRowText_C'] = anonymize(xMyRowText_C, 'MyRowText_C')
    retVal = json.dumps(MyRows, 'utf-8')
    return retVal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = NameDataset() ## Right here is good - THIS WAS THE BOTTLENECK ##
    retVal = main()
    sys.stdout.write(str(retVal))
```

Comment: if this is not involving the database, please remove tag `[mysql]`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing

```
for word in words:
    newword = word
    #regex for findind/splitting the words
    fRegExStr = r'(?=[^\s\r\n|\(|\)])(\w+)(?=[\.\?:,!\-/\s\(\)]|$)'
    pattern = regex.compile(fRegExStr)
    regx = pattern.finditer(word)
```

meaning that you `regex.compile` *exactly same thing* in each turn in loop, whilst you can do it before loop begin and get same result.

I do not see other obvious optimizations, so I suggest to [profile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) code to found what part is most time consuming.

Comment: Thank you @Daweo. Bottleneck was initialising 'm = NameDataset()' on each call. Moved it to main() - now its acceptable fast. Thanks as well for the hint with profile!